# Sed replace a part of a path with the current directory

Tags: regex, linux, unix, sed

I have a file containing a lot paths. I need to replace all those path (containing build numbers) by the current path.
In other word in my file I have like :

`/build/8b7yrg_k/12/src/main/myfile`

and I want (if I'm in /build/home/0/):

`/build/home/0/src/main/myfile`

What I'm trying is to do :

`sed 's,/build/'.+'/'[0-9]+'/','$PWD',g`

But the the command doesn't find the pattern. I also tried to add \ or to remove the ' but I don't manage to match the desired patterns

Comment: If you're executing this in some shell, then string interpolation happens only when using the `"` character. You're using `'` and be more careful about matching the characters.

Comment: Does the file contain a list of paths only? Or for example is it a script, containing paths throughout it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several issues:

- In POSIX BRE patterns, `+` is treated as a literal char, not a quanitifier
- In single quotes, variable expansion is not enabled
- The replacement is missing a slash (even if you fix the above, the current directory will appear glued to the remaining part of your path).

You can use

```sh
sed -E 's,/build/[^/]+/[0-9]+/,'"$PWD"/',g'
sed 's,/build/[^/]*/[0-9]*/,'"$PWD"/',g'
```

*Details*:

- `/build/[^/]+/[0-9]+/` is a POSIX ERE regex (enabled with `-E`) that matches `/build/`, one or more chars other than `/`, then a `/`, one or more digits and then a `/` chr
- `/build/[^/]*/[0-9]*/` is a POSIX BRE pattern that does the same as above
- `"$PWD"/` - the current directory variable is inside double quotes, and the `/` is added to make this replacement pattern work.

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/CZoomF):

```sh
#!/bin/bash
s='/build/8b7yrg_k/12/src/main/myfile'
sed -E 's,/build/[^/]+/[0-9]+/,'"$PWD"/',g' <<< "$s"
sed 's,/build/[^/]*/[0-9]*/,'"$PWD"/',g' <<< "$s"
```

Output:

```
/home/3octv4/src/main/myfile
/home/3octv4/src/main/myfile
```